# TYPO3 custom page type internal link

Tags: typo3

I made a custom page type for Blog articles according to the documentation [1].

All works fine, but making an internal link with a Link Browser or the CKeditor Link button is not possible to a Blog page. The page in the page tree is then grayed out, just like for example a sysfolder.

Is this possible with configuration?

[1] https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/master/en-us/ApiOverview/PageTypes/Index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though the documentation states there is no longer a limit to doktyp < 200, there still is a limit for the linkhandler.

> In TYPO3 versions below 10.4, the doktype was restricted to numbers smaller than 200 if the custom page type should be displayed in the frontend, and larger than 200 when it is just some storage. This limitation no longer exists, so you can choose a number at will.

When setting the doktype lower than 200, a link can be made.